# Trigger a Jenkins Job when a PR is raised - Should be one of the Status Checks

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have gone through numerous post on triggering Jenkins build when a PR is raised in github.

I have checked Git hub Pull Request Builder Option in jenkins job. Apart from above , I have added webhook and jenkins Github plugin as service in my repo.

How do I add status checks?

Anything else being missed here. I dont see build getting triggered when PR is raised.

Comment: please use generic webhook plugin for jenkins. please follow instructions found at https://bit-basics-backup.netlify.app/2019/september/jenkins-job-github-pullrequest/

Comment: I had struggled to get jenkin ci cd pipeline working, this worked finally, let me know how it went.